# Webpack + vue-loader + postcss-modules results in empty $style object

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, css-modules, vue-loader

In my app I'm initializing a Vue app, which uses single file .vue components.
I use Webpack to bundle, and [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) + [postcss-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) to generate scoped classes.

But for some reason I can't access the generated classes inside my components (`$style` object is empty). I'll explain the problem below and created **[this repo](https://github.com/sn3p/webpack-vue)** as an example.

My **hello.vue** component looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="$style.hello">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "hello",
  created() {
    console.log(this.$style); // <- empty object :(
  }
};
</script>

<style module>
.hello {
  background: lime;
}
</style>
```

**hello.vue.json** is generated as expected (CSS Modules mapping):

```
{"hello":"_hello_23p9g_17"}
```

Scoped styles are appended in the document head, and when using [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) it is bundled in **app.css**:

```css
._hello_23p9g_17 {
  background: lime;
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and possibly how to fix this?

Below my config files.

[**webpack.config.js**](https://github.com/sn3p/webpack-vue/blob/master/webpack.config.js) (trimmed for readability)

```js
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build")
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".vue", ".json", ".css"],
    alias: {
      vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm.js"
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          // MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              // modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css"
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ident: "postcss",
  plugins: {
    "postcss-preset-env": { stage: 0 },
    "postcss-modules": {}
  }
};
```

---

### EDIT:

FYI, setting `modules: true` in the `css-loader` options works in that it populates the `$style` object (see [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage)):

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        modules: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But in our app we use `postcss-loader` (as per [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#postcss)) that takes care of all transformations including scoping. Enabling both `modules: true` and `postcss-modules` conflicts and breaks the classes/mapping (as expected).

**In other words, I'm looking for a way to omit the `modules: true` option and enable css modules using `postcss-modules` instead.**

Comment: You commented out `modules: true`: you need that for CSS modules to work.

Comment: @Terry I know.. but I'm using `postcss-modules` instead. Enabling `modules: true` breaks the mappings as both implementations are applied (see edit in my post).

Comment: What about using [this trick](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#css-modules) instead?

Comment: This is kinda what I'm doing already. The problem is that this conflicts as css modules transformations are applied two times (through `css-loader` and `postcss-modules`) which results in broken style mappings. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

**Found a workaround:** manually import the styles from the JSON file.
If anyone knows a better way please let me know :)

**hello.vue.json**

```
{"hello":"_hello_fgtjb_30"}
```

**hello.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div :class="style.hello">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import style from "./hello.vue.json";

export default {
  name: "hello",
  beforeCreate() {
    this.style = style;
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.style);
  }
};
</script>

<style module>
.hello {
  background: lime;
}
</style>
```

This only works when using `postcss-modules` (loaded from config by `postcss-loader` in my case) instead of using `modules: true`:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        importLoaders: 1
      }
    },
    "postcss-loader"
  ]
};
```

See [this PR](https://github.com/sn3p/webpack-vue/pull/1) as a full example.